# Using recursion to draw nested Triangles

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'd like to draw a series of nested triangles using recursion.

My faulty code below:

```
def recursiveTri(x, y, shrink):

    tt.penup()
    tt.setx(x)
    tt.sety(y)

    if x > -10:
        return

    for element in range(3):
        tt.pendown()
        tt.forward(x)
        tt.right(120)

    recursiveTri(x + shrink, y - shrink, shrink)

def main():
    recursiveTri(-300,300,30)

main()
```

The current code produces the following:

[image: Actual output]

Here is what I mean by nested shapes, except that I would like to draw triangles instead of squares:

[image: Nested squares]

Comment: are you using any library? what are your imports?

Comment: @Babydesta. `import turtle as tt`. It's heavily implied, and the code is pretty unambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```
tt.forward(x)
```

Remember that your `x` is always negative, and the length of a side is not `x`, but rather `-2 * x`, if you want to be symmetrical about zero. Since your triangles are nested, you can also compute the initial `y` from `x`, given that it is 1/3 of the way up the main bisector. `-sqrt(3) / 3 * x` therefore puts the center of the circles circumscribed around and inscribed in your triangle at 0, 0.

In fact, it is probably easier to just fix the length of a side, and compute `x` and `y` from that:

```
import turtle as tt
from math import sqrt

def recursiveTri(side, shrink):
    if side < 10: return

    tt.penup()
    tt.goto(-side / 2, sqrt(3) / 6 * side)

    tt.pendown()

    for _ in range(3):
        tt.forward(side)
        tt.right(120)

    recursiveTri(side - shrink, shrink)

tt.penup()
tt.home()
tt.dot()
recursiveTri(300, 30)
```

In this case, `shrink` is the total amount removed from each side. If you want it to be the amount you step forward, change the recursive call to `recursiveTri(side - 2 * shrink, shrink)`.

The result (without multiplying `shrink` by 2) is

[image: Nested triangles]

Answer (score 3):

And now, just for fun, the "better living through *stamping*" solution:

```
import turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def recursiveTri(side, shrink):
    if side > 10:
        turtle.shapesize(side / CURSOR_SIZE)

        turtle.stamp()

        recursiveTri(side - shrink, shrink)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('triangle')
turtle.fillcolor('white')

recursiveTri(300, 30)

turtle.dot()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

[image]

This is the default orientation, you can turn it anyway you want before calling `recursiveTri()`.  *Stamping* is an alternative to *drawing* that works best with simple geometric patterms like this.